# How to push mongo objects into Neo4j

Tags: node.js, mongodb, neo4j

I'm writing a code which I need to push a data first into mongo and after successful insertion of that data I want to push it into neo4j. The data in the mongo frame can not get pushed into Neo4j. It throws the error below:

```
{ Neo4jError: Cannot pack this value: function() {
    var numArgs = arguments.length,
        states = utils.args(arguments, 0, numArgs - 1),
        callback = arguments[numArgs - 1];

    if (!states.length) states = this.stateNames;

    var _this = this;

    var paths = states.reduce(function(paths, state) {
      return paths.concat(Object.keys(_this.states[state]));
    }, []);

    return paths[iterMethod](function(path, i, paths) {
      return callback(path, i, paths);
    });
  }
```

I have not added a function as a value inside the data, unless it is a mongo object default property.

I am writing my code in NodeJS and I use mongoose and Neo4j driver for Nodejs.

I tried using a test data which is mentioned bellow. The main values of the test data was the same as mongo inserted object and it worked fine. But when the data is the real mongo insertion result it doesn't work.

```
{
    "ruid": "123kl2",
    "puid": "lkajsdlk2",
    "chiefComplaint": "a chief complaint",
    "diagnosis": "a diagnosis",
    "subRecords": [],
    "creationDate": [],
    "refForm": "someone"
}
```

I insert the doc in mongo in the code below and give the result to a function responsible for pushing that data into Neo.

```
 var newRecord = new Record();
 newRecord.chiefComplaint = req.body.data;
 newRecord.puid = numberFromBefore;
 newRecord.save((err, monDoc) => {
   if (err) throw err;
   neo.recordPush(monDoc, (error, neoRes)=>{
       if (error) throw error;
       else{
           res.status(200).send({
               ret: true,
               id: monDoc._id
           });
       }
   });

 });
```

In the neo functions the recordPush function is as below:

```
exports.recordPush = function (mainObject, callback) {

  session.run(
    "WITH $main_object_ as mainObject " +
    "MATCH (p:Patient {puid: mainObject.puid }) " +
    "CREATE (rec:Record {ruid: mainObject.ruid}) " +
    "CREATE (p)-[r:Suffer]->(rec)",
    {
      main_object_: mainObject,
    }
  ).then(function (result) {
    console.log('saved for ' + mainObject.puid);
    callback(null, result);

  }).catch((err) => {
    callback(err, null);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try inserting a mongo object into Neo4j via Neo4j Doc Manager https://neo4j.com/developer/mongodb/ or you can use APOC library to interact with MongoDB https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/database-integration/mongodb/